# Autocomplete return value seperately in two textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

How can make the autocomplete form return value in two different textbox? for example when select apple by using autocomplete form it will display "Apple" in textboxA and quantity "1" in textbox B.

I have tried the following code and succeeded to build the autocomplete form. But it show `name` in the selection and when select the item from list it will display `value`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CardName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/CardHolderDetails/Index",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.CardName, value: item.CardId };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "CardName" } })
        </div>  


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "CardId" } })
        </div>
```

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(string Prefix)
        {
            List<CardHolderDetails> getCardList = new List<CardHolderDetails>();
            getCardList = _service.getCardList();
            List<CardHolderDetails> ObjList = new List<CardHolderDetails>();
            foreach (var value in getCardList)
            {
                ObjList.Add(new CardHolderDetails { CardId = value.CardId, CardName = value.CardName });

            }

            //Searching records from list using LINQ query
            var CardName= (from N in ObjList
                            where N.CardName.StartsWith(Prefix)
                            select new { N.CardName, N.CardId });
            return Json(CardName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

i expected when select the output from autocomplete form, the output `CardName` will be in textbox A and `CardId` in textbox B.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand what the issue is exactly, but it's not clear - did you, or did you NOT get the autocomplete to work? Is it returning any meaningful value back to the client?
Anyways, with what we have here, it seems that there might be an issue with the Razor usage, probably with the way you're using the returned object:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "CardName" } })
    </div>  


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "CardId" } })
    </div>
```

From the model you're returning to the client and the Ajax script piece, I'd expect for the usage of the result 'model' object to look like this:
`model => model.label` and `model => model.value`.